# Remove background color of input tag in generated PDF

Tags: tcpdf

I have a problem using TCPDF form example #14, I want to remove the background color of input tag, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: without any code, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/examples/example_014.php here you can find code

Comment: You can't do that using `TextField()`.

Comment: Using writeHtml method input fields is not showing in pdf file 'not making editable field'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
// print some text
$text = 'This is an example of <strong>JavaScript</strong> usage on PDF documents.<br /><br />For more information check the source code of this example, the source code documentation for the <i>IncludeJS()</i> method and the <i>JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference</i> guide.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.tcpdf.org">www.tcpdf.org</a>';
$pdf->writeHTML($text, true, 0, true, 0);

$js = <<<EOD
var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, length = inputFields.length; i < length; i++) {
    var inputField = inputFields[i];
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
EOD;

// set javascript
$pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

Or this one:

```
// define some HTML content with style
$html = <<<EOF
<!-- EXAMPLE OF CSS STYLE -->
<style>
    h1 {
        color: navy;
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 24pt;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    input {
        background-color: red;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
</style>

<h1 class="title">Example of <i style="color:#990000">XHTML + CSS</i></h1>
<input type="text" value="test.." />

EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: i want to remove default color(grey) only transparent, in your solution color removed on focus.

Comment: How is the default color set? Via CSS? You can not just "remove" a default color. You need to specify what color it should have instead. The browsers default color e.g. will be white.

Comment: I don't know how this color is set.. i need your help to find out where this color is defined. are you understanding that i am talking about pdf file not just html page...?

Comment: yes but when i download pdf file, input tags initially showing some backgroundcolor screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

I have reset *FormDefaultProp* values before call the *$pdf->TextField()* function and works great!

```
$pdf->setFormDefaultProp();
$pdf->TextField('example', 50, 5);
```